# Method Directory.GetDirectories failures

Tags: c#, .net

Very odd that I am experiencing a occasional errors when calling the GetDirectories() method.

This started happening when our IT dept remotely moved some folders to my local machine. This error only occurs when navigating through these folders using C#.

Error Message: '**Access to the path 'C:\Users\XXXX\XXXXX is denied**'

Code:

```
public static string[] GetDirectoryInfo(string path)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        //This call is failing on the new folder.
        return Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    }
    return new string[0];
}
```

Not very complicated, correct?

Navigating with Windows Explorer, the folder isn't present.

In the CMD prompt I can change directory to this folder; following up with the DIR command I get the error 'File not found'.

I am guessing 
the problem is a Win32 issue and something didn't get cleaned up when the folder was moved.  I have no idea how to correct the issue, except for digging through decompiled System.IO classes; which I will do if I don't get a solution.

Comment: you have file not found errors but you said TO your computer. I'm confused. If the folders are visible in explorer, check permissions otherwise I think ILSpy is your best bet to figure out why it might be faulting.

Comment: No, folders in question are not visible in Explorer. Permissions aren't the issue, that was the first thing I checked. I am always looking for new tools, so I will check out ILSpy. Thanks.

Comment: Permissions are the issue.  Ask the IT dept to fix this for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is probably trying to access hidden folders that are not accessible to your account/role.

The easiest solution is to catch the `UnauthorizedAccessException` and just eat it, so it essentially skips the directory, like this:

```
public static string[] GetDirectoryInfo(string path)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        try 
        { 
            //This call is failing on the new folder.
            return Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException unAuthEx)
        {
            // Do nothing to eat exception
        }
    }
    return new string[0];
}
```

Comment: Yes that would be the easiest, and it has already been implemented, until (if) I can find a solution.  I wanted to keep the question simple, but the folders in question are Environmental.SpecialFolders that were deleted somewhere during the move process and the mappings are still present (guess). That is what I need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the software tries to access folders which have been restricted by the windows for security reasons like for example :

```
C:\Users\Default  (This path is not accessible by your code)
```

Another reason would be that your application is trying to access folders which are not really folders like

```
My Music
My Pictures
```

If you are trying to read all the folders in a specific drive, then you can make some exception to handle these directories, another thing that MIGHT help you is to run your application as administrator.